# Replace &#39; with an Apostrophe '

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a column called `LastName` in a GridView and it is pulling data correctly; however, people whose last names include an apostrophe `'`, like O'Connor, it shows up as `O&#39;Connor`.  How do I make it show an apostrophe and not a code?  I am aware of a code `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode(TEXT to ENCODE)` which fixes such issue but I do not know how to apply it to the BoundField or if it will work in the BoundField?  Please help.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" 
                SortExpression="LastName" />
```

Comment: try setting `HtmlEncode="false"` on the BoundField? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: sure thing! i'll submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `HtmlEncode="False"` should work:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName"
    HtmlEncode="False" />
```

More info: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)